# Salto de línea PHP

Tags: php

En el siguiente código intento insertar un salto de línea para separar el texto original de la traducción.

```
 <?php 

            $text = "Hola Mundo"; 

            $translation = str_replace("Hola Mundo", "Hello World", $text);
            echo "Texto Original: Hola Mundo" . PHP_EOL , "Resultado: " , $translation; ; 

        ?>
```

Al ejecutarlo no se muestra ningún cambio. Ejercicio didáctico.

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres que se muestre? Si es en  la consola, `\n` o `PHP_EOL` 
 causará un salto de línea; si es en HTML, necesitarás un `<br>`.

Comment: Me gustaría mostrar el salto de línea en el navegador web, intenté insertar un br pero no puedo ponerlo dentro del la etiqueta <php? ?> ¿verdad?

Comment: Lo puedes  poner dentro de las comillas: `echo "Texto Original: Hola Mundo<br>Resultado: " , $traduction;`

Comment: si es para el navegador web, pudieras hacerlo así `$text = "Hola Mundo"; 
$traduction = str_replace("Hola Mundo", "Hello World", $text);
echo "Texto Original: Hola Mundo"."<br>". "Resultado: ".$traduction;`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, no sabía que se podían implementar etiquetas html dentro de las comillas

Comment: `  echo "<p>Texto Original: Hola Mundo</p>" , "<p>Resultado: $translation </p>";` ¿Imprimir la variable `$translation` de la siguiente forma es correcto?

Comment: `echo "<p>Resultado: ".$translation."</p>";` solo te faltaba concatenar correctamente

Comment: @nauumb pon lo que has encontrado como respuesta. De ese modo, si otra persona se encuentra con un problema similar, podrá usar tu pregunta/respuesta como referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar un salto de línea en nuestro navegador web, se ha de utilizar la etiqueta `<br>` o como en el ejemplo siguiente, incluir al imprimir etiquetas `<p></p>` que realizarán directamente el salto de línea, al ser etiquetas de bloque. Han de ser añadidas dentro de nuestro código php de la siguiente forma `" echo <etiqueta>Contenido</etiqueta> "`. Además se pueden concatenar usando los operadores `.` o `.=`.

```
  <?php 

            $text = "Hola Mundo"; 

            $translation = str_replace("Hola Mundo", "Hello World", $text);
            echo "<p>Texto Original: Hola Mundo</p>" . "<p>Resultado: " . $translation . "</p>"; 
        ?>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], si bien esta es la respuesta a tu problema lo mejor sería explicar como este script soluciona el problema

Comment: Espero que haya quedado algo más claro. Muchas gracias por el consejo.

Answer (score 0):

Es tan sencillo como agregar un 
 asi....

```
<?php 

$text = "Hola Mundo"; 

$translation = str_replace("Hola Mundo", "Hello World", $text);
echo "Texto Original: Hola Mundo <br> Resultado: " , $translation; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilza la función `nl2br(string)` auxiliándote de `\n`.

```
<?php 
    $text = "Hola Mundo"; 
    $translation = str_replace("Hola Mundo", "Hello World", $text);
    echo nl2br("Texto Original: Hola Mundo\n Resultado: " , $translation); 
?>
```